# Getting illegalStateException when accessing coroutines in main thread

Tags: android

I have written the code given below to fetch the data from local DB and update it to my recycler view. I am using `Dispatchers.IO` to fetch the data from DB and using `Dispatchers.main` to update my list in recycler view. But I am not able to access the dispatcher Main Module. I am calling the below function in my fragment:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Main) {

    eventList = withContext(IO) {
        shruthiDatabase.eventDao().getAllEvent() as ArrayList<Event_Entity>
    }

    if (eventList.isNotEmpty()) {
        eventAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        eventRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        eventFound.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the error message here

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem in your dependencies. Sometimes Main Dispatchers not work when versions do not match

```
COROUTINES_VERSION = "1.3.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$COROUTINES_VERSION"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$COROUTINES_VERSION"
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with `Coroutines` i'll advise that you declare a `Coroutine Scope` which contains the `Context` and the `Job`. By this I mean:

```
private var job = Job()

private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)
```

You can wrap the code below in a function say `getEventList()` which you can then call at any point.

```
uiScope.launch{
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        eventList = shruthiDatabase.eventDao().getAllEvent() as ArrayList<Event_Entity>
        if (eventList.isNotEmpty()) {
            eventAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            eventRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            eventFound.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```